Primes such that a given number has very small order
The following came up in (a previous version of) this answer.
Question. Let $a > 1$ be a positive integer, and $f \in \mathbf Z[x]$ a polynomial with positive leading term. Does there always exist a prime $p$ such that the order $m$ of $a \in (\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ satisfies $f(m) < p$?
If $P(n)$ denotes the largest prime factor of $n$, then the question can be reformulated as follows: given $a > 1$, does there exist $m$ such that $P(a^m-1) > f(m)$? Indeed, the above version implies this one by taking the same $m$ and $p$. For the converse, first replace $f$ by a monotone $g$ dominating $f$ (i.e. $g(n) \geq f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbf N$). If $p > g(m)$ divides $a^m-1$, then the order of $a$ modulo $p$ is a divisor $n \mid m$. Then $p > g(m) \geq g(n) \geq f(n)$ gives the version above.
For instance, if $a = 2$, this is certainly true if there are infinitely many Mersenne primes, since $2^q \gg f(q)$ for $q \gg 0$. More generally, for any $a > 1$, it is conjectured that $\tfrac{a^q-1}{a-1}$ is prime for infinitely many (necessarily prime) values $q$.
But these conjectures seem well out of reach at the moment. The version above feels much weaker, asking for polynomial rather than exponential growth. Is this something that can be proven with current techniques in analytic number theory?
For example, when $f$ is linear, this follows from the result of [Ste75] that $P(a^q-1)/q \to \infty$ as $q \to \infty$ (prime), and this is certainly something I expected could be proven unconditionally. But that result is a bit stronger, namely an asymptotic. I'm only asking that $P(a^q-1)/q^n$ takes on arbitrarily large values for every $n$, making it a "lim sup" problem instead of "lim".
Per Will Jagy's suggestion, this is in turn equivalent to the function $\log(P(a^q-1))/\log(q)$ being unbounded above.

References.
[Ste75]  C. L. Stewart, The greatest prime factor of $a^n-b^n$. Acta Arith. 26 (1975), p. 427-433. ZBL0313.10007.

Your question reminds me of the lemma by van der Waerden at the start of the development of class field theory in Lang's Algebraic Number Theory (Lemma 1 in Section 2 of Chapter X in the 2nd edition): for each $a > 1$ in $\mathbf Z^+$ and each prime power $q^r$, there is a prime $p$ such that $a \bmod p$ has order $q^r$.

Just checking. For a fixed base $a,$  finding a sequence of primes for which
$ \log_{ord} p $  increases, and conjecturing that it increases without bound?
jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./order_small 2
base  2 prime 3  order  2        log(p) / log(ord)    1.58496     
base  2 prime 7  order  3        log(p) / log(ord)   1.77124     
base  2 prime 31  order  5        log(p) / log(ord)   2.13366     
base  2 prime 127  order  7        log(p) / log(ord)   2.48942     
base  2 prime 8191  order  13        log(p) / log(ord)    3.51305     
base  2 prime 131071  order  17        log(p) / log(ord)   4.15906     
base  2 prime 524287  order  19        log(p) / log(ord)   4.47277     

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./order_small 3
base  3 prime 5  order  4        log(p) / log(ord)  1.16096     
base  3 prime 11  order  5        log(p) / log(ord)  1.4899     
base  3 prime 13  order  3        log(p) / log(ord)    2.33472     
base  3 prime 547  order  14        log(p) / log(ord)  2.3889     
base  3 prime 757  order  9        log(p) / log(ord)  3.01715     
base  3 prime 1093  order  7        log(p) / log(ord)   3.59558     
base  3 prime 34511  order  17        log(p) / log(ord)   3.68805     
base  3 prime 363889  order  19        log(p) / log(ord)   4.34874     
base  3 prime 797161  order  13        log(p) / log(ord)    5.29789     

jagy@gost:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./order_small 4
base      4 prime         3    order  1  
base      4 prime         5    order  2     log(p) / log(ord)   2.32193   
base      4 prime       127    order  7     log(p) / log(ord)   2.48942   
base      4 prime       257    order  8     log(p) / log(ord)   2.66854   
base      4 prime       683    order  11     log(p) / log(ord)   2.72176   
base      4 prime      2731    order  13     log(p) / log(ord)   3.08483   
base      4 prime      8191    order  13     log(p) / log(ord)   3.51305   
base      4 prime     43691    order  17     log(p) / log(ord)   3.7713   
base      4 prime     65537    order  16     log(p) / log(ord)   4.00001   
base      4 prime    131071    order  17     log(p) / log(ord)   4.15906   
base      4 prime    524287    order  19     log(p) / log(ord)   4.47277   
base      4 prime   2796203    order  23     log(p) / log(ord)   4.73411  


Ok, I still have some difficulty understanding the notation, but I think I agree that this is what I want. Asking that a certain quantity $p(m)$ (in this case $P(a^m-1)$) grows faster than any polynomial in $m$ means exactly that $\log(p(m))/\log(m)$ gets arbitrarily large. (It's up for debate whether $p$ depends on $m$ or the other way around.) For $a=2$ ('base 2'), the largest known Mersenne prime gives a 'high score' of $\log(2^{82589933}-1)/\log(82589933) > 3140365$.
